# Problem:Save Several Duplicate posts in The Database and then Error nesting level of '100' reached

Tags: actions, array, duplicates

I have a function to insert a single post in the database.

But when I run the function, duplicate posts (40) are added to the database and then an error is displayed.

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\cache.php on line 671

I would like it so that each time the function is run only one post is saved, without duplicates.

```
function ghoolo_mango(){

    $oiobz1 = writeMsg(1, 'center', '', 1);
    $postdate =date('Y-m-d');
    $ta =date('Y-m-d');
    $postdate_gmt =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $titles='زندگی'.$postdate;
    $posts = array(
        'post_content'   => $oiobz1,
        'post_name'      => $titles,
        'post_title'     => $titles,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_author'    => '1',
        'ping_status'    => 'publish',
        'to_ping'        => 'http://rpc.pingomatic.com/',
        'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_date'  => $postdate,
        'tags_input'     => ", قیمت طلا در امروز $ta, قیمت طلا در امروز ,قیمت امروز طلا $ta,قیمت طلا $ta , قیمت امروز طلا $ta, قیمت طلا ماه $ta,لیست امروز قیمت طلا $ta,دانلود لیست قیمت طلا $ta,$ta قیمت طلا به روز,قیمت روز طلا,قیمت ",
    );

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($posts);
    ghoolo_mango();

}
add_action('wp', 'ghoolo_mango');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code you are calling the function `ghoolo_mango()` by using the the `wp` actoin hook.  This is fine but be aware that it will add your post **everytime a page loads**.

The problem is that you are also calling the function `ghoolo_mango()` within the function itself - i.e. it will keep calling it over and over.

To fix the problem, remove the line `ghoolo_mango();` at the end of the function.

Your code should look like this -

```
function ghoolo_mango(){

    $oiobz1 = writeMsg(1, 'center', '', 1);
    $postdate =date('Y-m-d');
    $ta =date('Y-m-d');
    $postdate_gmt =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $titles='زندگی'.$postdate;
    $args = array(
        'post_content'   => $oiobz1,
        'post_name'      => $titles,
        'post_title'     => $titles,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_author'    => '1',
        'ping_status'    => 'open',
        'to_ping'        => 'http://rpc.pingomatic.com/',
        'post_date_gmt'  => $postdate_gmt,
        'post_date'      => $postdate,
        'tags_input'     => ", قیمت طلا در امروز $ta, قیمت طلا در امروز ,قیمت امروز طلا $ta,قیمت طلا $ta , قیمت امروز طلا $ta, قیمت طلا ماه $ta,لیست امروز قیمت طلا $ta,دانلود لیست قیمت طلا $ta,$ta قیمت طلا به روز,قیمت روز طلا,قیمت ",
    );
    
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);
    
}
add_action('wp', 'ghoolo_mango');
```

---

## Edit

You have now also asked how to insert future posts.

To do this, all you have to do is change the post date to a future date and change the post status to `future`.  Because you include the date in your title, you'll also need to update that, but it should be as simple as this -

```
$postdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' + 1 day');
$postdate_gmt = new DateTime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' + 1 day');
$titles='زندگی' . $postdate->format('Y-m-d');
$args = array(
    { other args... }
    'post_status' => 'future',
    { other args... }
);
```

In the example above I've used **1 day**, but you can alter that as required.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I have Another question ... In The top code // 'ping_status'    => 'publish' But I don't know When save in the database  not publishing rather futuring .. @David Gard

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I also noticed that in the original answer `pint_status` was set to `publish` - this can only be `open` or `closed`, so make sure you update your code accordingly.